# Can I use Design View in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: c#, linux, visual-studio

I have a Visual C# project and I opened it with Visual Studio Code(the IDE) so can I use Design View to edit?

Comment: It is a code editor, not IDE, https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/editor/whyvscode so not likely to have Design View in near future.

Answer (score 2):

It is a code editor, not IDE, [Why Visual Studio Code?](https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/editor/whyvscode) so not likely to have Design View in near future.
                    – Lex Li